# Is it possible to change ng-model value without ng-change function?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Is it possible to change ng-model value without ng-change function??
The following method is not work

```
<div ng-app="myApp">
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
<input id="checkbox" type="checkbox" ng-model="field">
 <div> {{field}} </div> 
</div></div>    

<script>
var myapp = angular.module('myApp', []);
myapp.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope){

if(document.getElementById("checkbox").checked){
$scope.field="YES";    

    }})
```

but use the following code is work for me

```
<div ng-app="myApp">
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
<input id="checkbox" type="checkbox" ng-model="field" ng-change="change_text()">

<div>{{field}}</div>
```

```
  <script>
    var myapp = angular.module('myApp', []);
    myapp.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope){

    $scope.change_text = function() {  
    $scope.field="YES";        
    }})
  </script>
```

Comment: what is `choice`? where is it defined?  the controller is only executed once, when the page loads, so it isn't exactly going to respond to user interaction, the way your first code is trying.

Comment: also, it's not really clear how your second example would work, since it is only adding the `change_text` function if `choice == true`, but it's really still not obvious what `choice` is.

Comment: it might be helpful if you actually show your HTML where you are using `ng-change`, since your question asks about it but you aren't really showing that part or what it is meant to do.

Comment: Thx Claies, I upload for my code, I hope it is clear for the question

Comment: What you are trying to do is going to break.  `ng-model` on a checkbox expects the model (in this case, `field`) to be `true` or `false`.  Your `ng-change` is changing the type of `field` from a Boolean `true` / `false` to a String type, which will make `ng-model` invalid.  if you are going to have your `field` be a string, then you can't use `ng-model`.

Comment: also, the first example still wouldn't work, since the controller is only executed when the page loads, and the checkbox would probably not be checked yet at that point, especially if your model isn't really a Boolean anyway.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To accomplish what you are trying to do, you can use `ng-true-value` and `ng-false-value` to have your model be a type other than a boolean without breaking the two way data binding with `ng-model`.

for example:

```
<input id="checkbox" type="checkbox" ng-model="field" ng-true-value="'YES'" ng-false-value="'NO'">
{{field}}
```

Pass the values for `ng-true-value` and `ng-false-value` as string literals (wrapped in the extra quotes).

http://plnkr.co/edit/hjuwOV6q6iZOaXv89M6x?p=preview